# Reg Ex Help to find instances of ".xl" between brackets

Tags: regex, vbscript

I'm awful with RegEx and am in a time crunch. I'm trying to come up with a rule that will pull out instances of text captured between brackets that also include the phrase ".xl" in them.

**Example String:**
C:\Users[chris.xlm]\Desktop[Test1.xlsx]Sheet1'![$C$4]

**What would get captured from the expression would be:**
1. chris.xlm
2. Test1.xlsx

Comment: What "flavor" of regex?  In other words what language or tool are you using?  From the tag's description: "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable"

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't realize that. I am using VBA. My reference library just calls it "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions"

Answer (score 1):

The pattern:

```
\[([^]]+?\.xl.*?)\]
```

should accomplish what you [need](https://regex101.com/r/09juLh/1/).

The pattern grabs everything before and after any presence of *.xl* if it is in the text, including the full extension.

Revised thanks to C Perkin's comment.

Comment: Caution: Although this uses non-greedy operators, it will not limit the match to within a single set of brackets if the brackets don't contain `.xl` Example:  `C:\Users[chris.docx]\Desktop[Test1.xlsx]Sheet1'![$C$4]` would match `[chris.docx]\Desktop[Test1.xlsx]`  The use of +? and *? also depends on the regex flavor, but that has not yet been specified by the OP.

Comment: The pattern did work for me, however @CPerkins point is a great callout. Is there any way to get around that issue?

Comment: `\[([^]]+?\.xl.*?)\]`